# Can I get the projects links via the SonarQube Web Service API

Tags: sonarqube

We want to get the project links (Home, Continuous integration,...) via the SonarQube Web Service API.

The links belong to the CoreProperties - https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/CoreProperties.java

Is it possible to read them via the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible yet. But with the UI refactoring that is currently done on 5.2, this is likely that such a WS will be developed.

Comment: I will update the ticket once I can create a JIRA ticket for this.